# Secure my applications

Tags: security

I try to secure my application that does not use internet so it will be installed locally ((on a local workstation)).
I am also looking to give users the possibility to rent my application so how to activate any service just on my application for a period gives.
NB: the program in c ++.
thank you beforehand.

Comment: I really don't have a clue what you are asking...

Comment: Indeed, I would restrict access to the features of my program with the use of a license number to determine the period of using my software so I rent the software for a period of time (e.g. two months) after these two months the software blocks must essential functions of the latter so that it makes the customer to subscribe a so once I have my program secures against all uses that are not permitted I know I can uses a license number but my software is installed in a workstation that contains no internet so there is no need to connect.

Answer (score 0):

Use a licensing system. 
By this you can ask the user to buy a license key for your product as most of the software vendor does..

I found a pretty interesting resource which you may find it useful.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/99499/Implementation-of-the-Licensing-System-for-a-Softw

Hope that helps,

Best.